# How do I turn my windows 7 laptop into a remote server?

Tags: windows-7-x64, remote-server

I need to turn my laptop into a remote server.  It's running Windows 7.  A full explanation isn't necessarily needed, just a point in the right direction would be sufficient.  Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will likely need to do the following steps

- Set up port forwarding on your router (port 80 for a web server)
- Set up a server on your laptop (Apache web server)
- Use your public IP address or use a service such as [Managed DNS](http://dyn.com/dns/)

Comment: Your IP will likely also be dynamic, not static. So you'd either need to obtain a static IP from your ISP (which may be a paid-for extra), or use a dynamic DNS service.